# pthread_join wrong type of argument

Tags: c, pthreads, pthread-join

I've been trying to create a simple thread that reads from stdin and stores input to a linked list. When creating and joining the thread I get the following error:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘pthread_join’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   pthread_join(prod_thread, NULL);
```

I'm passing a thread_t* argument to pthread_join but it seems that it expects an int which confuses me. Can anyone explain why this is happening? Here is the code:

```
pair_t* head = malloc(sizeof(pair_t));
pthread_t* prod_thread = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));
pthread_create(prod_thread, NULL, prod_func, head);
pthread_join(prod_thread, NULL);
```

The prod_func function looks like this:

```
void* prod_func(void* head) {
  ...
}
```

I've also tried calling `pthread_join(&prod_thread, NULL);` but then I get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm passing a thread_t* argument to pthread_join but it seems that it expects an int which confuses me.

[`pthread_join`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) expects its first argument to be a `pthread_t` (not a `pthread_t *`).  Exactly what type `pthread_t` actually is varies from implementation to implementation, but in your implementation it is an integer type.  You are passing a pointer instead.

> I've also tried calling pthread_join(&prod_thread, NULL); but then I get the same error.

Of course you do.  if `prod_thread` has type `pthread_t *` then its address, `&prod_thread`, has type `pthread_t **`.  That's going the wrong direction (and the result is still a pointer).  As you have written your declarations, what you actually want is

```
pthread_join(*prod_thread, NULL);
```